# Xilinx SDK undefined reference to '__local_ctype_ptr'

Tags: c, sdk, embedded, xilinx

I'm taking a project that was developed and compiled with a previous version of Xilinx SDK, not sure what version I'm thinking 2018, and I'm using 2019.1 to build.

I have several errors that produce the diagnostic:

```
undefined reference to '__local_ctype_ptr'
```

These errors are linked to such functions as `isdigit`, `tolower` and etc.

I can select '*Open Declaration*' on the function and the SDK will take me to the `#define` in 'ctype.h' and when I back track I see where in 'ctype.h' there is the statement

```
const char *__locale_ctype_ptr(void);
```

I do know why I'm getting this error when I can go to the declaration, is the library that is defining these functions possible not loading in my project? What is the library that holds these functions?

Any suggestions/help would greatly be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: `__locale_ctype_ptr != __local_ctype_ptr`

Comment: All diagnostics are useful, copy and paste them verbatim - do not abstract or elide you may be omitting useful information.

Answer (score 0):

Updating to a new version of Xilinx SDK often requires rebuilding the BSPs because they may reference old static libraries in the SDK.

Right-click the project and perform a "Re-Generate BSP Sources".